# facebook renew user token after 60 days

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use this code to get a valid token for 60 days

```
// Set Extended Access Token
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
//get session
$session = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

then i store it in the database and use it to post on the user's wall(*publish_stream* permission). However is there any way to renew the token, my user is unlikely to open the app in these 60 days (building a reminder app).

Please provide working code or how to for dummies

Comment: You can not renew the token just like that. User interactin with your app is required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you can extend a token more than 60 days or renew it without user interaction.

**But**, if your user by any chance goes to your app during the 60 days, the token will be renewed automatically and it'll get another 60 days of lifetime.

> Expiration and Extending Tokens
>
> Facebook's official SDKs manage the lifetime of tokens for you. When
>   using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making
>   sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.
>
> Native mobile applications using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived
>   access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed
>   once per day when the person using your app makes a request to
>   Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire
>   after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login
>   flow again to get a new token.
>
> Access tokens on the web often have a lifetime of about two hours, but
>   will automatically be refreshed when required. If you want to use
>   access tokens for longer-lived web apps, especially server side, you
>   need to generate a long-lived token. A long-lived token generally
>   lasts about 60 days.

Also on the docs they say you shouldn't depend on these lifetimes, since users can revoke permissions, change his password (*changing password will revoke every token for every app the user has installed*)

> User access tokens come in two forms: short-lived tokens and
>   long-lived tokens. Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about
>   an hour or two, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of
>   about 60 days. You should not depend on these lifetimes remaining the
>   same - the lifetime may change without warning or expire early.

All this info I quoted is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, The facebook does not provide any method for refreshing access token without user interference. The user must re-login the app to catch a fresh token, In this case the only benefit you get is that you catch fresh token without authorized dialog.